# How to cancel all asynchronous operations in single thread of Boost asio multithread server?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I would like to implement single thread termination of server, allowing to continue execution of 
operations (accept, read, write) for another threads.
Should i use own acceptor object for each thread ?
Does  exist api functionality for that or i should implement register of sockets, where i will mark up, which socket belongs thread ?
Currently, i implement that thread's loop:

```
void TServer::Process_connections(IThread* _th, TThcode _idx)
{
    const char * FUNCTION = __FUNCTION__;
    using namespace boost::asio::ip;
    using namespace boost::asio;
    error_code ec;
    LOG + "s: server thread loop is started" << std::to_string(_idx);
    //auto m_pthread = m_pmngthread.get();
    auto isRunning = _th->isRunning();//m_pthread->isRunning();
    while(isRunning)
    {
        if ((m_state(state::running)))
        {
            do_accept(_idx);
            //m_state << state::run;
            break;
        }
        isRunning = _th->isRunning();
    }
    while(isRunning)
    {
        if (m_state(state::run))
        {
            try
            {
                m_ioservice.poll(ec);
            } catch (...)
            {
                errspace::show_errmsg(FUNCTION);
                m_state << state::shutdowned;
            }
            if (ec) break;
            clearGarbage();
        }

        isRunning = _th->isRunning();//m_pthread->isRunning();
    }
    LOG << "s: server thread loop is stopping";
    // only for single thread server
    m_acceptor.cancel(ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        errspace::show_errmsg("error in acceptor::cancel");
    }
    // only for single thread server
    m_ioservice.run(ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        errspace::show_errmsg("error in ioservice::run");
    }
    std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex>  lock(m_mtx_garbage);
    std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex>  lock2(m_mtx_active);
    m_socketset_garbage.clear();
    m_socketset_active.clear();
    // only for single thread server
    m_acceptor.close();
    if (ec)
    {
        errspace::show_errmsg("error in acceptor::close");
    }
    LOG + "s: loop is stopped" << std::to_string(_idx);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve solution where each client has its own thread that deals with the accept/read/write of that client _only_, or are you OK with a thread being able to service requests from multiple clients?

Comment: my solution is a few threads and a few clients in each thread.

Answer (score 0):

Only if by cancel you mean stop: [io_context::stop](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/stop.html)